# Is it the same to use express.json than bodyParser?

Tags: javascript, json, api, express

I have a question that is not clear to me yet. Is it the same to use express.json() as to use body-parser module? What is the difference? How does one benefit from each other? Right now I am creating an API that returns json and after reading the documentation it has not been very clear to me.

Comment: From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html): "`express.json([options])`... This is a built-in middleware function in Express. It parses incoming requests with JSON payloads and is based on body-parser." So yes, they should be similar, since one is based on the other. IMHO I generally favor built-in functionality when possible over adding additional libraries, unless they have enhanced capabilities I need.

Comment: express.json got removed for a while. As a built-in function. So that's where I think the confusion comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They essentially do the same thing. When Express 4.0 was released, they removed some of the middleware that used to come with express (e.g express.json). This meant we needed to get our own Json parsing middleware - bodyparser, allowing us to then use  `app.use(bodyParser.json())` instead of the old/built-in `app.use(express.json())` that would no longer work.

As these patch notes for [Express 4.1.16](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0) (2nd bullet) shows, they added back in so that express now has that functionality again. You could now use either. I believe both ways (`body-parser.json()` and `express.json()`) should function identically if you have the newest version of Node.